# Place small UIImage in large UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton of approximate size 60px by 60px and I have to place an UIImage in it. The Image is placed in this way:

```
var emptyHeart = UIImage(named: "Red_Heart_Empty_x23px.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
self.favouriteButton.setImage(emptyHeart, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

The image should be 24*21px. However if I resize the image with Photoshop to this size, even by choosing 300 resolution, the icon appears smudged. If I choose a larger version of the image it fills up the whole button. Ideally I would need a clear 24*21px image. I still tried adjusting the larger version in the button, but it doesn't work. I tried

```
1) self.favouriteButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(17, 21, 0, 0);
2) self.favouriteButton.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 21)
```

The first one gives very weird effects and the second one doesn't work at all.

Comment: you are taking into account the retina screen right? i.e need double size image for 24*21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your problem could the fixed by providing several levels of image resolution. You will end up by adding Red_Heart_Empty_x23px@2x.png, and Red_Heart_Empty_x23px@3x.png for the higher density screens.

There's a few apps out there that help size files into @2x and @3x versions automatically. I can't speak for all of them but the one I use is called Prepo and it has been good to me.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought that by placing an image double the size it would show up as double as large, but we're talking about resolution here, not size